# Plot if variable is unique

Tags: r, plot

I am new to R and struggling with making a plot.

**What?**

I have a dataset that simplified looks like this:

| Article | Client | Revenue Client |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 500 |
| Second | 2 | 1400 |
| third | 3 | 1000 |
| third | 2 | 1400 |
| fourth | 1 | 500 |
| fifth | 3 | 1000 |

The revenue client is for the same client always the same and is total products they bought. I would like to have a density plot for every unique client that plots its revenue. I just have no clue how to do this. If you could help me out, that would be great.

**Code**

Not giving desired result

```
for (i in unique(Book1_1$`Werf adres`))
  {
  # Kernel Density Plot
  d <- with(Book1_1[Book1_1$`Werf adres`==i,],  density(Book1_1$`Omzet 19/werf`) # returns the density data
  plot(d)
  polygon(d, col="red", border="blue")
}
```

Comment: Do you want to plot only unique clients (ignoring those who appear multiple times, as your title suggests), or have one summarizing plot per client?

Comment: I want to plot unique clients, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code subsets the data to the first row per client and subsequently plots the kernel density estimate of the total revenues. I assume that the data frame is called *df*, the client id variable *Client*, and the revenue variable *Revenue*.

```
require("tidyverse")

group_by(df, Client) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(Revenue)) + 
    geom_density()
```

Comment: I am not sure I was completly clear what i want to achieve, my aplogies. I want to see how the revenue per client is distributed. So for each unique client it's total revenue (Omzet 19/werf) and see the distribution of this. Because the clients pop up a lot (and so does its total revenue cause this is always on the same row), i don't want dulicates of this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for such a solution?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)
df %>% 
  mutate(Client=factor(Client)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x=Revenue_Client, group=Client, fill=Client), alpha=0.5, adjust=2) +
  theme_pubclean()
```

[image]

data:

```
structure(list(Article = c("First", "Second", "third", "third", 
"fourth", "fifth"), Client = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), Revenue_Client = c(500L, 
1400L, 1000L, 1400L, 500L, 1000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```